# transform double click on Z to double click on mouse

Tags: actionscript-3

When I click 2 times on the touch "z" (keycode 90) on my keyboard, my item is removed.

```
timer=new Timer(500, 1);
stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, removeDraggedItem);

private function removeDraggedItem(e:KeyboardEvent){
             if(timer.running==true)
            {
                if(e.keyCode==90)
                {
            stageRef.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragItem);
            stageRef.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, itemHitTest);
            draggedItem.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, itemClick);

            stageRef.removeChild(draggedItem);
            toolbar.useText.text = "";

            if (stageRef.contains(this))
                stageRef.removeChild(this);

            Mouse.show();
            Engine.playerControl = true;
                }
            }

            else if(e.keyCode==90)
            {
                timer.start();
            }
        }
```

I'd like to change it and when we click 2 times with the mouse the item is removed but I can't figure out how to do it... if mouseDown = true ? it does'nt seem to work...

EDIT :

Ok I've tried to change (e.keyCode==90) by (e.buttonDown). No errors but nothings is happening when I double click...any idea why ?

Comment: have you tried `MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK`? `stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, myFunction);`

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work..(for Adobe AIR ANDOIRD)

Comment: but apparently MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK is not working well and we have to set a timer...

Comment: if(event.buttonDown) doesn't work either... (error 1120) .Maybe I need to import something as import flash.events.MouseEvent; or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only listening for a `KEY_UP` event: `stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, removeDraggedItem);`. You should add a `KEY_DOWN` event as well and then use the `KEY_DOWN` event in conjunction with the `KEY_UP` event to check for a double click. The code to add a `KEY_DOWN` event is `stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, functionName);`.

On another note if your trying to use `MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK` you have to enable double click for the object you wish to double click. Oh and definitely include `flash.events.MouseEvent`

`object.doubleClickEnabled = true;`
`object.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, functionName);`

Also I noticed in your `removeDraggedItem` function, you start a timer if the keycode equals 90. Then the next time a `KEY_UP` event is thrown you check if the timer is running and if so you remove a lot of event listeners and objects. You never stop the timer or reset the timer or remove the timer, I was just wondering if that was intentional?